# How do I save a string from database query using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to save data into a string that can later be used.

this is the code that I have thus far:

```
$phone_numbers = $this->phone_model->get_all()->result();

$string = '';
foreach($phone_numbers as $cel){
    $string .= 'Phone #: ';
    $string .= $cel->cel_num;
    $string .= '<br/>';
}
$data['string'] = $string;
```

my database has:

```
id    cel_num
1     1324567890
2     1515744243
3     6516515225
```

There can be more or less

Then in my view I just have it as `echo $string` to echo the data

```
$html .='
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<table width="90%" align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
    <tr>
        <th style="font-size:14px;" align="center">'.$contact->name.'<br />
            <div style="font-size:10px">
            '.$contact->addr.'<br />
            ////////// HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO ECHO THE NUMBERS/////////
            '.$string.'
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;" align="left">
    PHONE BOOK</th></tr>
</table>';
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: when I try to echo them in my view

Comment: Where's the code that does the echoing?

Comment: @pmahomme the code is updated!! :)

Comment: Is any of this being echoed, or just `$string` isn't working?

Comment: just string is not being echoed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120644/discussion-between-learningbyexample-and-pmahomme).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array and that is why you need a foreach loop. Here is the code that you need. I'll change it into something more simpler.

**CONTROLLER FUNCTION**

```
function display_numbers()
{
    $data['phone_numbers'] = $this->phone_model->get_all();
    //I made this into an array and removed the result, 
    //we will be getting that from the database.

    //I removed the String part for it is maybe not necessary, I'll echo it in the view

    $this->load->view('my_view', $data);
}
```

**MODEL FUNCTION**

```
function get_all()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('your_table');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
    //This way we return this result automatically to the call
}
```

**View**

> Important note, Don't mix php with html, or if you can don't over do it.

```
    <table width="90%" align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
        <tr>
            <th style="font-size:14px;" align="center">'.$contact->name.'<br />
                <div style="font-size:10px">


                 <ul>
                 <?php foreach($phone_numbers as $cel) ?>
                   <li> <?php echo $cel->cel_num  </li>
                 <?php endforeach ?>
                 </ul>


                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;" align="left">
        PHONE BOOK</th></tr>
    </table>';
```

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

change your :

```
$data["string"] = $string
```

to this

```
$data["string"][] = $string
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!